# Ionic File DOWNLOAD

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to download a song/file from a local server using the FileTransfer cordova plugin .
Some links actually work and the song is downloaded, but when testing it on my phone, I can't even find the song.

Please help

```
let dest = cordova.file.dataDirectory  + this.currentSong.title+".mp3";
//cordova.file.externalRootDirectory;
fileTrnsfr.download(uri,dest,true).then(
  (entry)=> {
    console.log("Downloaded");

    const alertS = this.alertCtrl.create({

            title: "Download Succeeded",
            subTitle : "File saved in " + dest,
            buttons:['Ok']
    });

    alertS.present();
  },
(error) => {

    console.log("An error occured  " + error);

    const alertF = this.alertCtrl.create({

      title: "Download Failed",
      subTitle : "File downloading failed :"+ dest + " from" + uri,
      buttons:['Ok']
    });

    alertF.present();
}
```

);

});
}`

Comment: which phone (ios / android) you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I you are using android and having the same issue,
it means there is no write permission.
you can provide that by adding this line of code.

1. open `manifest.xml` file
2. path is `appdir/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml`
3. add this line.
   `< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
4. Check in download file.
5. Rebuild / rerun you will get issue resolved.